# Qt Creator open ui.qml file in editor by default

Tags: qt

In Qt creator whenever you open a `ui.qml` file by double clicking or CTRL + TAB the file normally opens in design mode. To see the code, you need to hit ESC to go the text editor. I want that the `ui.qml` files should open by default in the editor. How can I do that in settings?

Comment: If you want to edit ui.qml files by hand, don't use ui.qml files? These are made to be edited by the designer and are limited to a small subset of qml because of that. Just use the normal qml extension!

Comment: @rubenvb I never thought of it this way! Can we use the editor on simple .qml files without a problem?

Comment: yes, of course, `.ui.qml` files are "new", `.qml.` files have existed since the beginning of QML. For more information, see http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-ui-forms.html.

Comment: @rubenvb Thank you, this was useful. Learning QT is kinda tough. I couldn't find a 'serial guide' to learn it. Could you please point me to a reference that you think may help me out? Also, if I don't get a better answer, I'd like to accept yours.

Comment: it helped me a lot to define a simple/intermediate project that could be attacked step by step and covered a lot of different things and just start writing bits and pieces of it. It helps if you focus on a single thing in the Qt documentation, preferably with an example. Qt is the best documented framework of them all (no kidding), but step one is to learn to use the documentation. Load up a simple example, e.g. the Basic Layouts, or Application example) which can be loaded from Qt Creator. read the examples' explanation, the code, and the associated documentation.

Comment: Also, learn basic C++ first. That at least you won't struggle with the language while learning a framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to edit `.ui.qml` files by hand, don't use `.ui.qml` files?
These are made to be edited by the *designer* and are limited to a small subset of QML because of that.
Just use the normal `.qml` extension in this case.

More info on QML UI files [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-ui-forms.html).

Comment: Couldn't find a better answer, thanks for your guide in comments as well!

Answer (score 7):

In Qt Creator:

1. **Tools** >>> **Options**;
2. Open **Environment**;
3. Go to **MIME Types**;
4. Find (by filter, for ex.) `application/x-qt.ui+qml`;
5. Delete or change **Pattern** field in *Details*.

Comment: In details there are no pattern fields. I tried the solution before posting the question.

Comment: I'm on QT Creator 3.6.1, what version are you using?

Comment: As I can see you don't have anything in the Details box too.

Comment: Cause I deleted a pattern already. Don't you forget select a MIME type firsly?

Comment: I followed all 4 steps and 5th is the one which I can't because there never existed one. I'll try to update and see if that works.

Comment: I managed to install 4.0.0, there still isn't any pattern in there.

Comment: It's very strange behaviour. Maybe you can try reset all and then try select that mime and watch, what it'll say.